# Raising and handling events in separate processes

Tags: c#, events

Here is the gist of my problem

1. Process A raises an event
2. Process B on possibly another machine, catches the event and does something

Is this at all possible with the .net framework?  Every single example I've looked at has the event producer and consumer in the same process/application on the same machine.  Sometimes they are in the same thread, sometimes they are in different threads but they are always in the same process on the same machine.

I can achieve the desired effect with event handlers using sockets to send the event from one process to another and raising an event on the receiving end.  This seems like a very roundabout method, since I have to create event ids,  serialize/deserialize the arguments and play with a whole load of socket code, which is the same as what I did in C in the 90s.

The question for now is

How do I send events from one process to another on the same machine using the .net framework event mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a lot like Inter Process Communication (IPC), for which several mechanisms exist, with varying degrees of support in non windows Systems. There is WCF, remoting and memory mapped IPC, off the top of my head. In practice I found using a light weight pub sub mechanism like zeromq to be the most adequate solution.

Comment: So what you're sayings is there is no built-in mechanism for handling events across processes.  We have to use WCF or some form of IPC.  That's good enough for me.

Comment: There is also Event Tracing for Windows (ETW), but not sure about delivery guarantees, etc. Could make that work as well probably, but at the core it's IPC with higher level API. If you found my answer useful, would you mind accepting it?